# During a chroot attempt, I got this error: "chroot: failed to run command '/bin/bash': Exec format error"

Tags: bash, chroot

I was following the instructions of this tutorial [HOWTO: Purge and Reinstall Grub 2 from the Live CD](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1581099), when I encountered an error at step 1, as I launched the command

```
sudo chroot /mnt/temp
```

The error was the following:

```
chroot: failed to run command `/bin/bash': Exec format error
```

Where does that come from? How do I get through?

Answer (score 26):

Verify that you are using the right Live CD. For example, verify you are not using a 32bit CD instead of a 64bit CD. You need a 64bit kernel to run 64bit code, so check your architecture.

Assuming you mounted your system to be chrooted in **/media/sda1**, to determine the architecture you can:

`ls /media/sda1/*`

if you see lib64 in the output, it's probably a 64bit system

Comment: It is but still cannot chroot

Answer (score 8):

I had the same problem when making an image for armhf arch. I had to install `qemu-user-static` and then copy it to chroot bin folder.

```
sudo cp /usr/bin/qemu-arm-static /path/to/mount/usr/bin
```

You may have to run

```
systemctl restart systemd-binfmt.service
```

then you should be able to chroot into the environment

Comment: Work fine for me!

Note: mkdir and cp this file before running debootstrap command

Comment: Changed my machine and had this issue, forgot about the qemu stuff. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

The error means that your jail (`/mnt/temp`) does not contain a bash shell, or does not contain the libraries required to run the bash shell.

If you created your jail using something like this:

```
debootstrap --variant=buildd --arch i386 lucid /mnt/temp \
    http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/
```

You probably meant to do this instead:

```
debootstrap --variant=minbase --arch i386 lucid /mnt/temp \
    http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/
```

However, as a technical answer to your problem, try:

```
cp -r /bin /lib /mnt/temp
```

This should allow you to chroot successfully, at which point you can do other things.

There are about a million things wrong with doing that though, and almost certainly you do not want to do that. Use minbase when you create your jail, or install ubuntu on a blank target (eg. a virtual machine) and create a tar archive of the entire system which you then decompress into `/mnt/temp`.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I was using a new Linux VM installation as ther host for `chroot`, This VM did not have the `qemu` and `binfmt` packages installed.
Error: `chroot: failed to run command /bin/bash: Exec format error` got solved installing below packages:

1. `sudo apt install qemu-user-static`
2. `sudo apt install binfmt-support`

Just to clarify, the Linux VM was using `ubuntu-20.04`, `x86_64` and to be chrooted system was `armhf` i.e. `32-bit` system.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed this is a 64-bit 32-bit incompatibility.

Although with

```
cp /bin/bash /mount/temp/tmp
```

(copies 32-bit exec to the new root in the `tmp` directory

```
chroot /mount/temp /tmp/bash
```

`chroot` is fine, all commands still fail. You would have to copy them all over.

Answer (score -1):

In my case, I was trying to chroot into a 64-bit version of Linux but my current Linux was 32-bit.

I had mounted a disk image (master image, for replication on multiple machines).

Comment: Same answer as @GrandOxymore's above.

Comment: @KarlRichter Similar but not the same.  Running 32bit program in a 64bit OS is not the same as running a 32bit program in a 64bit virtual environment (or OS).  I could run a 32bit guest os and it would have run fine.