# Do I have to completely reinstall Ubuntu now that it won't boot?

Tags: installation, boot, partial-upgrade

I just tried installing software called Teamviewer. It said there was some kind of error with unresolved dependancies. Then I realized I was trying to install the 32 bit version, but I needed to install the 64 bit version. So I tried that, and I got an error saying that Ubuntu needed to do a partial upgrade.

I thought that was weird, so I just wanted to abandon installing anything and get out of this. I exited all programs and rebooted, and now I can't get back into Ubuntu. After the GRUB screen I get a black screen and no login options.

If I boot into recovery, I get the following screen:
[image]

I booted up a live CD of 12.04 to see if that could help, but it seems the only option is to completely reinstall Ubuntu.

Can I repair this in any way, or is my only option to make a fresh install?

Comment: This appears to be a duplicate question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/123124/ubuntu-doesnt-boot-after-apt-get-upgrade-black-screen

Comment: @hnasarat It isn't a duplicate because he isn't booting to a "black screen".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<sub>Proceed with **extreme caution**. Having sufficient backups is encouraged at all times as you are just one step away from having to reinstall your entire system. Also, I don't claim responsibility for any possible disastrous outcomes. Good luck and all the best.</sub>

*A not so great idea at fixing your problem.*

You could try chrooting from a LiveCD of the same architecture and try and fix the broken packages.

**Note:** chrooting will fail if it is not of the same architecture. For example, you can only use a 64-bit LiveCD if your partition is also 64-bit. Or else, chrooting will fail midway. You can check your architecture with the command `uname -m`.

Run `sudo fdisk -l` and take note of the partition where your Ubuntu install is installed.

Create a directory in `/mnt` for mounting the partition later on:

```
sudo mkdir /mnt/1
```

Assuming the file system of the partition is of the type `ext4`, mount the partition at `/mnt/1`.

```
sudo mount -t ext4 /dev/sda5 /mnt/1
```

If you entered a wrong filesystem type, you will get an error similar to this:

```
$ sudo mount -t ext3 /dev/sda5 /mnt/1
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sda10,
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error
       In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
       dmesg | tail  or so
```

If you are not sure of the filesystem, mount the partition in your File manager and then run `df -T`. Take note of the filesystem type and then unmount and  mount it with the correct filesystem type:

```
sudo umount /dev/sda5
```

Now that you have correctly mounted it, chroot it to the previously created directory at `/mnt`.

```
sudo chroot /mnt/1
```

If you get `chroot: failed to run command /bin/bash no such file or directory`, [try copying `/bin` and `/lib` to `/mnt/1`](https://askubuntu.com/questions/14280/during-a-chroot-attempt-i-got-this-error-chroot-failed-to-run-command-bin) and try chrooting again.

```
sudo cp -r /bin /lib /mnt/1
```

Now that you have chrooted into the system, try fixing the broken package through `apt-get update && apt-get upgrade`. If there are any unresolved broken or unmet dependencies around, try to clean it up.

- [How do I resolve unmet dependencies after adding a PPA?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies)

Hopefully, you now managed to resolve and remove any corrupt packages that might have previously stalled your boot process.

Any other extraordinary situations arising at this point of time demands [its own question.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/ask)