# Ubuntu does not recognize partition with EFI (Windows 8.1 installed on this partition)

Tags: boot-partition

Good afternoon everyone !
I install Ubuntu 15.10 Wily Werewolf next to Windows 8.1.
But did not show the option to install next to the windows.
So I went to partition manually.
Installed Ubuntu ext4 partition on / dev / sda4 and swap on / dev / sda5.
The windows were in / dev / sda1, sda2, and sda3.
Friends, when I restart it went up in windows.
I did a test, and I disabled UEFI boot and left active, only Legacy boot.
Now only goes up Ubuntu.
I believe this is fully related to UEFI and Legacy.
If someone can help me solve ....
I've given an update-grub and nothing to solve.

follows print of fdisk -l

[image]

Grub-update Results

[image]

Comment: Please edit your question giving information such as Windows' version, architecture of both Operating Systems and what you see in the GRUB menu.

Comment: ok .......   Edited.

Comment: "When the grub carrega" kkkkkkkk br é br. Please, English only.

Comment: ..................Right.

Comment: If you installed Ubuntu in BIOS boot mode, system cannot boot UEFI install. UEFI & BIOS are not compatible. But you can dual boot from UEFI boot menu or one time boot key like f10 or f12. Or you can reinstall grub in UEFI mode. To know for sure how you have installed, boot this in UEFI mode: Post the link to the Create BootInfo summary report. Is part of Boot-Repair:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info

Comment: I decided .... I'll put an answer exactly what I did .....

Answer (score 4):

In Ubuntu, open a terminal window and run:

`sudo update-grub`

That should update GRUB's configuration file and recognize your Windows installation.

Comment: That's a good start. It may also be necessary to http://askubuntu.com/questions/493612/how-to-reinstall-grub

Comment: Already did.
Not solved.
It recognizes only the partitions with ubuntu ...

Answer (score 1):

If you are meeting with 'Grub' on booting your system.
Then the option should be available to boot from windows in the grub menu,(I'm Specifying even this because your question was unclear --Incase you are a beginner--)

Other possibility is that Ubuntu(Grub) haven't recognized windows, So add a direct entry from 'Grub Configuration file'. If you think it is hard to do it.

Make a bootable Windows USB and boot from it and click on repair this pc.

After doing it you will not be able to got to Ubuntu, so now you download 'Easybcd' application for windows and then add that drive to the boot menu.
Now you are good to go.

Remember the drive naming of your Ubuntu(i.e.,sda5 ,in your case)
Now choose the same in easy-bcd.

If you get confused by for selecting the drive of Ubuntu, remember that it is the partition above swap.

I Hope this was Helpful.

Comment: Oh, come on! Make a Windows bootable USB, repair the whole thing and install EasyBCD to make Windows visible to Ubuntu? That's ridiculous. And making Windows USBs involves legal conditions.

Comment: Not to make Windows visible to EasyBcd :::: It's to make Ubuntu visible to the MBR partition.(There were two operating System's were Installed in it)

Comment: Of-course Your answer was simple, but i mean it in case if that didn't work. Because it didn't recognize Windows boot-loader in First case

Comment: Please gentlemen, updated the question ... look there ....

Comment: yes proceed as i said

Answer (score 0):

I ran the live ubuntu and formatted by gparted the entire HD.
After I created a new partition table ... I created as msdos.
The previous partition table was gpt.
After I installed windows 8 and then Ubuntu alongside Windows 8 without any problems.
It is interesting to all professionals study more about partition tables, EFI and the like.

Now fixed annexed follows the print:

[image]