# Can't recognize Windows 10 on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: boot, dual-boot, windows-10

I am a new Ubuntu user. Last night I installed Ubuntu 16.04 to dual boot with Windows 10, but now I can't see Windows 10 in the boot menu - although all of the Windows system files and folders are shown in my laptop.

When I boot, there are only three options:

```
 1. Ubuntu 
 2. Advanced options for Ubuntu 
 3. System setup
```

I tried to install Ubuntu again, but after some stage it says:

- Erase all and install Ubuntu 16.04 LTS
- Install Ubuntu 16.04 LTS alongside Ubuntu 16.04 LTS..., etc.

Now what can I do?

- How can I get back into Windows 10?
- After getting into Windows 10, what should I do next time to properly dual boot Ubuntu with Windows 10?

Comment: You need to update and repair grub. Answers already exist here on how to do that. for instance: http://askubuntu.com/questions/493612/how-to-reinstall-grub

Answer (score 1):

This is a common problem for users who have installed Ubuntu on a system that already had a Windows partition. Running [**Boot Repair**](https://askubuntu.com/questions/217904/unable-to-boot-into-windows-after-installing-ubuntu-how-to-fix#answer-218006) should solve this issue for you:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair
boot-repair
```

If not, then [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/217904/unable-to-boot-into-windows-after-installing-ubuntu-how-to-fix#answer-217970), or any of the other 15 answers, to this question, [Unable to boot into Windows after installing Ubuntu, how to fix?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/217904/unable-to-boot-into-windows-after-installing-ubuntu-how-to-fix), will probably help you fix GRUB and enable you to see your Windows partition again.

It could also be worthwhile running

```
sudo os-prober
```

to see if your Windows partition is still bootable.