# No windows after installing Ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, boot, dual-boot, grub2, windows

Yesterday I installed Ubuntu, however, after the install had finished there were no bootable operating systems. Neither my Windows 10 or Ubuntu would launch. After reading around I found repair boot, made a live CD, and "fixed" the grub. This allowed me to launch my Ubuntu OS but it still would not let me launch my Windows 10.

This brings me to a few hours ago. Since then I have not been able to fix my system so it launches Win10. I can mount my hard drive that had my Win10 OS on and that was not touched during Ubuntu setup, I have tried the methods [here (except manually writing an entry)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/197868/grub-does-not-detect-windows).

I have also tried booting on the HDD that has the partition for Win10 but that provides me with a black screen and a flashing white line. The same result that I had before I ran boot repair and got Ubuntu to work.

So I am asking how can I boot into windows, either by booting onto the hard drive that contains it or adding it to the Grub Ubuntu launches off?

**Edit**
I forgot to mention my secure boot is disabled so that is not the issue here

**Edit**
*lsblk*

```
NAME                MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda                   8:0    0  58.7G  0 disk 
├─sda1                8:1    0   243M  0 part /boot
├─sda2                8:2    0     1K  0 part 
└─sda5                8:5    0  58.5G  0 part 
sdb                   8:16   0   2.7T  0 disk 
├─sdb1                8:17   0   128M  0 part 
└─sdb2                8:18   0   2.7T  0 part 
sdc                   8:32   0   1.8T  0 disk 
├─sdc1                8:33   0 927.3G  0 part 
├─sdc2                8:34   0   450M  0 part 
└─sdc3                8:35   0 935.3G  0 part 
sr0                  11:0    1  1024M  0 rom
```

*sudo lshw | grep -A9 firmware*

```
 *-firmware             
      description: BIOS
      vendor: American Megatrends Inc.
      physical id: 0
      version: F2
      date: 07/15/2013
      size: 64KiB
      capacity: 4032KiB
      capabilities: pci upgrade shadowing cdboot bootselect socketedrom edd int13floppy1200 int13floppy720 int13floppy2880 int5printscreen int9keyboard int14serial int17printer acpi usb biosbootspecification uefi
     *-cpu
            configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half firmware=rtl8168e-3_0.0.4 03/27/12 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
            resources: irq:28 ioport:b000(size=256) memory:fe200000-fe200fff memory:da100000-da103fff
    *-pci:5
         description: PCI bridge
         product: SB900 PCI to PCI bridge (PCIE port 2)
         vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
         physical id: 15.2
         bus info: pci@0000:00:15.2
         version: 00
         width: 32 bits

            configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath9k driverversion=4.3.0-kali1-amd64 firmware=N/A ip=192.168.1.128 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11abgn
            resources: irq:18 memory:fe100000-fe11ffff memory:fe120000-fe12ffff
    *-usb:5
         description: USB controller
         product: SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB OHCI0 Controller
         vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
         physical id: 16
         bus info: pci@0000:00:16.0
         version: 00
         width: 32 bits
```

Comment: It sounds like your grub bootloader wasn't installed correctly. See http://askubuntu.com/questions/493612/how-to-reinstall-grub

Comment: @MarkYisri You did notice that the OP said " I can mount my hard drive that had my Win10 OS on and that was not touched during Ubuntu setup"

Comment: Have you installed ubuntu at the mounting point "/"?

Comment: @JulienChau I think I did, I just let the setup automatically partition and use my secondary SSD, the secondary SSD was just installed so Windows had nothing to do with it

Comment: @ElderGeek I reinstalled my grub with repair boot as originally neither OS would launch. Do you think I need to reinstall it again?

Comment: @ElderGeek would it be worth trying to add a manual entry?

Comment: @Dan Boot-repair should solve your problem. We need to determine why it didn't.  Please [edit] your post and include the output of `sudo lshw | grep -A9 firmware` and `lsblk` Thank you for helping us help you!

Comment: @ElderGeek I have included

Comment: Ok. We now know that you have a UEFI system due to "biosbootspecification uefi" Please confirm that you installed Ubuntu on the ~60GB SSD (sda) and your Windows drive is a ~3 TB Hard disk (sdb)

Comment: @ElderGeek Unbuntu is on the 60GB but the Windows is on SDC1

Comment: Interesting. There doesn't appear to be an EFI partition on that drive.

Comment: Is it possible that Windows is in hibernation mode (standard for windows 10) at the moment  you installed Ubuntu?  If yes turn it off in Windows. Exit windows.
3. Try boot repair or reinstall ubuntu

Comment: @JulienChau This whole question is about the fact I can't access Windows.

Comment: Use a Windows disc or live usb drive to initiate windows start-up repair. Remember that you should use the same one that is already installed on your computer.

Answer (score 0):

It would seem that your Windows was installed in BIOS mode  as there is no EFI partition on /dev/sdc but the system is currently in EFI mode per lshw output. You should be able change this setting in your BIOS to either UEFI and Legacy or Legacy and if nothing else is awry the system should boot. The aforementioned discrepency between boot mode and installation mode is very likely what is confusing boot-repair (which you will likely need to run again once your system is booting in the same mode that you installed your operating systems.

Comment: If in BIOS mode, you should have Windows boot loader on Windows drive and grub on Ubuntu drive. And if Ubuntu in gpt drive in BIOS mode it needs the bios_grub partition. And Windows 10's fast start up is always on hibernation which must be off to boot from Ubuntu. Otherwise you can only boot from BIOS. http://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/ubuntu-16-showing-windows-10-partitions and: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2324331&p=13488472#post13488472

Comment: @oldfred Well said once again!