# Can't boot from Lubuntu hard drive

Tags: dual-boot, lubuntu

I've been wanting to install Lubuntu for  a while, and I've had to jump through a lot of hoops to do so. First, the partition I created showed up as "unusable". I did a bit of googling and found this was a problem of having more than four partitions, which my HP laptop was shipped with. I ended up having to recycle the Recovery (D:) drive my computer came with for Lubuntu. However, after installing, my computer will not see the partition, from the boot menu and from Windows Explorer. It was formatted as ext2, which I assume Windows can't read. It shows up in Disk Management completely blank, with no name or drive letter, but it appears and says it has 19.2GB free (the original size of the disk). The drive does show up if I use the "Try Lubuntu" option when booting from the USB after it was installed. How can I boot from this disk?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to reinstall grub](http://askubuntu.com/questions/493612/how-to-reinstall-grub)

Comment: Where did you install grub. It needs to be in the MBR of drive like sda, but not partition like sda5. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair and: How to restore the Ubuntu/XP/Vista/7/8/10 BIOS bootloader 
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RestoreUbuntu/XP/Vista/7Bootloader and:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Installing#Fixing_a_Broken_System
Also while Windows works, make you you have a Windows repair flash drive.