# Grub2 not loading

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, boot-repair

I have been trying to set up Ubuntu to dual boot but after the install the GRUB2 bootloader is not starting. I tried boot repair but still nothing happening.

The link for the boot repair information is: [paste2.org/5xVcCmvX](http://paste2.org/5xVcCmvX).

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You haven't installed grub.

Comment: How do I go about installing? I thought it installed as part of ubuntu install...

Comment: Normally it does, You haven't provided enough information to determine what went wrong (usually operator error). See: http://askubuntu.com/questions/493612/how-to-reinstall-grub

Comment: Grub is installed for UEFI boot in ESP. You have an Acer which has unique requirement of setting an UEFI password and enabling "trust" on ubuntu/grub .efi files from UEFI. Also make sure you have newest UEFI from Acer: Acer Very latest UEFI/BIOS works, downgrade not required:
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2298380&p=13419141#post13419141
and
http://askubuntu.com/questions/706912/getting-a-black-screen-when-installing-or-live-booting-ubuntu-any-version-in-m?noredirect=1#comment1039248_706912
step 35
http://askubuntu.com/questions/627416/acer-aspire-e15-will-not-dual-boot

Comment: Thanks both. Turns out the peculiarities of acer were the problem and http://askubuntu.com/questions/627416/acer-aspire-e15-will-not-dual-boot solved it.