# Copying Directories and Files

Tags: 16.04, webserver

My Ubuntu 14.04 LTS server recently went down. I have rebuilt the server using 16.04 LTS. I started Live Version through CD without installing so I can take files from my backup External USB drive that have my configuration, WordPress files on it hoping to copy the /etc and /var and whatever else I would need off my back up to the new server install. When I try to do so I get a message I don't have permission. What do I need to do to set permission so I can get these files over to the new Install. Also are there any other files I need to bring over to get the website  to come online again" As always any help appreciated.

Comment: 14.04 uses upstart and 16.04 as I recall uses systemd. I'm not confident that your approach will be successful. By upgrading the OS mid-catastrophe you are opening an additional can of worms best left closed. Can't you simply restore your full backup?

Comment: That was the problem the back up when restored wouldn't boot. It had apparently created a EFI boot loader on the back up and didn't have the MBR record. I tried everything I could think of and it wouldn't boot. This install I disabled UEFI all together and when I did the install it created the MBR.

Comment: I still would revert to the backup and then simply [reinstall grub](http://askubuntu.com/a/493616/225694) since the actual problem you are having is your backup won't boot due to a missing boot record. Of course you'll want to confirm that you are booting in the same mode (EFI or Legacy) from the live media as your backup. If you made an image backup you can mount the image and confirm whether is has an EFI boot partition.

Answer (score 0):

When running the Ubuntu 16.04 Live option, you will be user unprivileged "ubuntu" by default. Besides that, /var/www/ on a server is typically user/group owned by the root (admin) user, which prevents writing to /var/www/ as unprivileged user, so you would use "sudo" to overcome this. 
You can e.g. do this in the Live Session :

```
sudo cp -av /media/ubuntu/backup-usb-disk/var/www/* /var-www-mountpoint/
```

Where /media/ubuntu/backup-usb-disk/var/www/ is your backup,
and /var-www-mountpoint/ is the /var/www/ folder on your fresh server install.