# After dual boot ubuntu 16.04 on my windows 10, there's no grub boot loader for ubuntu?

Tags: boot, grub2, uefi

I used to install Ubuntu on my acer notebook (travelmate p-246m) which is on UEFI boot, after boot with the live cd I choose something else to install Ubuntu. And I create the 4 Gb swap partition, 10 Gb home, and 36 Gb of root (which mounted as '/'). After done with the partition I prefer to install Ubuntu on windows boot manager. I take almost 1 hour to download some package and install after the installation complete, it tells me to restart the system. Whenever I used to restart my system it automatically get me into the windows 10. There's no GRUB boot loader. so what should I do now to get the GRUB boot loader ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to reinstall grub](http://askubuntu.com/questions/493612/how-to-reinstall-grub)

Comment: Newer threads, mention that newest UEFI from Acer works, do not downgrade. But Acer has unique UEFI requirement for setting "Trust" on grub/ubuntu's .efi boot files from UEFI. Acer E5-573G, downgrade UEFI, supervisor password & trust on Ubuntu efi boot files.
http://askubuntu.com/questions/706912/getting-a-black-screen-when-installing-or-live-booting-ubuntu-any-version-in-m?noredirect=1#comment1039248_706912
Acer Aspire E15 will not dual boot, many details Trust settings in step 35
http://askubuntu.com/questions/627416/acer-aspire-e15-will-not-dual-boot

Comment: Have a look on [Boot Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)