# Can't dual boot Ubuntu, Windows boots directly

Tags: dual-boot

I had not  any problem dual booting ubuntu before. Once I opened BIOS the dual boot menu was gone. It directly boots Windows now.  I didn't change anything in BIOS. How can I fix this? Thank you.

Comment: have you tried holding Shift down during boot?

Comment: Yes I did. It didn't work.

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/493612/how-to-reinstall-grub

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try booting from an Ubuntu USB and installing [Boot-Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair). You will need a [persistent install](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16988/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-to-a-usb-key-without-using-startup-disk-creator) for this, I think (haven't tried downloaded Boot-Repair onto a USB before). Try the "Recommended repair" first. If this doesn't work, you will be able to use the app to create a BootInfo summary that you can post here which will make it easier for others to solve your problem.