# dual boot problem after using os-uninstaller

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, boot-repair

I had two operating system on my computer.

I used os-uninstaller to remove window 8 from my computer, then I restarted my system but was unable to continue to Ubuntu and I get a message "no bootable device".

I tried to reinstall Windows but couldn't as it showed me that the partition can't be used because it is on NTFS.

Then I used a boot repair disk but the problem still exists. [This is the boot info summary](http://paste.ubuntu.com/25968248/).

Comment: How exactly are you running Boot-Repair? If it's a live system, from where did you get the boot image? Did you [verify its integrity](//help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM)? I'm asking because `/usr/sbin/grub-install` appears to be corrupted (see line 1445 of the Boot-Info log). It's possible to repair the Grub package but it's rather likely that other applications are corrupted too leading to unexpected system behaviour.

Comment: https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair-cd/home/Home/

Comment: Could you please get a Ubuntu live system, [verify its integrity](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM) and follow https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair#A2nd_option_:_install_Boot-Repair_in_Ubuntu. We don't know much about third-party distributions on Ask Ubuntu. Thanks.

Comment: You have an UEFI system and UEFI install, but somehow converted the ESP - efi system partition sda2 from FAT32 to NTFS. It must be FAT32 with boot flag to be seen as ESP. And now all references to ESP in fstab, grub, & UEFI are to now missing ESP. You will have to recreate ESP and at least a total reinstall of grub.  The reinstall of grub can be done from Boot-Repair's advanced options.

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/493612/how-to-reinstall-grub

Answer (score 6):

You have an UEFI system and UEFI install, but somehow converted the ESP - efi system partition sda2 from FAT32 to NTFS. It must be FAT32 with boot flag to be seen as ESP.

And now all references to ESP in fstab, grub, & UEFI are to now missing ESP. You will have to recreate ESP and at least a total reinstall of grub. The reinstall of grub can be done from Boot-Repair's advanced options.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/

Some brands of systems will only boot "Windows Boot Manager" as UEFI entry. That is a violation of UEFI standards, but it is by description only, so we can make booting Ubunutu's shimx64.efi have that description. You then boot Windows entry to actually boot Ubuntu. sdX is drive, Y is efi partition example for sda2

```
sudo efibootmgr -c -L "Windows Boot Manager" -l "\EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi" -d /dev/sda -p 2

man efibootmgr
```

http://askubuntu.com/questions/486752/dual-boot-win-8-ubuntu-loads-only-win/486789#486789