# GRUB recovery - help needed

Tags: grub2, mount, gpt

During Ubuntu startup (not remember exactly, but no newer than 16.04)

I got error

```
Minimal Bash-like line editing is supported. For the firs word, TAB list possible command completions. Anywhere eise tab list possible device or file completions
grub>
```

Tried to fix this by following [this instruction in russian from help.ubuntu.ru](https://help.ubuntu.ru/wiki/%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_grub).
Note: [english version is available on help.ubuntu.com](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2#Reinstalling%20GRUB%202).

```
Disk /dev/loop0: 1.5 GiB, 1612648448 bytes, 3149704 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


The primary GPT table is corrupt, but the backup appears OK, so that will be used.
Disk /dev/sda: 465.8 GiB, 500107862016 bytes, 976773168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 97EC9BD5-12A2-4852-94C0-30BAB6C4FD4A

Device         Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda1       2048   1050623   1048576   512M EFI System
/dev/sda2    1050624 960630783 959580160 457.6G Linux filesystem
/dev/sda3  960630784 976771071  16140288   7.7G Linux swap
```

The `sudo mount /dev/sda2 /mnt`

gives

```
mount: special device /dev/sda2 does not exist
```

Please help me.

Comment: Ask Ubuntu is an English Only site.  Please translate from Russian/Cyrillic into English using a translation service before posting your question.

Comment: @RupertSmith I translated your post. Important message above is *The primary GPT table is corrupt, but the backup appears OK, so that will be used.*. Please add output of `sudo blkid ; lsblk` to the question. If GPT is corrupt, then block devices may not be created. And of course write in English.

Comment: @ThomasWard please reopen. It is not user-friendly (OP seems to be newbie). Even after I have translated his post. You gave him 15 minutes. It is too fast.

Comment: @N0rbert "Too fast" or not, **post contents can still be edited after closure** and then that puts them into the Reopen queue whether it was mod-closed or not.  I was also live-monitoring this post for the update (translation, etc.) so the need to request for reopening (or critiquing how quickly this was closed for not being in English) is unnecessary.

Comment: @N0rbert 

sudo blkid ; lsblk

https://justpaste.it/4xygw

Comment: @RupertSmith I recommend to download [Boot Repair Disk](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) and follow its instructions to recover GRUB.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to reinstall grub](https://askubuntu.com/questions/493612/how-to-reinstall-grub)

Comment: @N0rbert Boot repair just gave me to create Bootinfo (only one button in app). Report here http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/gsXZM5mQH7/ . I launched OS with Try Ubuntu from USB

Comment: @N0rbert https://askubuntu.com/questions/493612/how-to-reinstall-grub after command [sudo mount /dev/sda2 /mnt/root] answer [mount: special device /dev/sda2 does not exist]